# Survey123 connect form's dropdown values are not visible in experience builder

Tags: arcgis

When connected survey123 form to experience builder, the dropdown values added in surve123 using CSV, are not visible in experience builder.

I added csv in arcgis online and share on organizational level.
The dropdown value directly added in excel form is visible but added through csv is not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the CSV file in media folder and in your CSV there should be 'name' and 'label' column.
and in survey form excel, add the select_from_one filename.csv and add some variable in label and name column, no need to add anything in choice excel.